# How do I use require inside a module with the parents context?

Tags: node.js, module, require

**app.js**

```
require('./modules/mod');
```

**modules/mod/mod.js**

```
modules.exports = () => {
   require('./modules/secondmodule');
}
```

Essentially I want the above code to be able to require modules, but using the same context that itself was called from, e.g. another module in the same folder, without having to use relative paths.

I thought [module.require()](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_require_id) did this, but it seems to give me the same error that require() was after I moved my code into the separate module (mod.js).

edit:

I have since discovered I can use `require.parent.module` and it seems to be working. Please let me know if this is not advised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`require` uses paths that are relative to current module. It's possible to do this by providing `require` from parent module:

```
modules.exports = parentRequire => {
   parentRequire('./modules/secondmodule');
}
```

Which is used like:

```
require('./modules/mod')(require);
```

It's correct to use relative modules instead because child module shouldn't be aware of the context in which it's evaluated:

```
require('../secondmodule');
```

In case `mod` has to be decoupled from `secondmodule`, dependencies can be provided to it with some common pattern, e.g. dependency injection or service locator.

Comment: Is that different than require.parent?

Comment: Do you mean `module.parent.require`? It would work too but I would strongly advise against it. A module shouldn't be hard-coded to be used with specific parent, this breaks the modularity. In this case I see no reasons to not use `require('../secondmodule')`. In case you want modules to be independent, you can publish them to NPM as private packages. Or use a thing like https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias .

Answer (score 0):

Secondary optional answer:

```
module.exports = () => {
   module.parent.require('./modules/secondmodule');
}
```